# Javascript for loop alert value one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a trouble with looping the json array in JavaScript. How do I get only SG_J1001 and SG_LS01? Actually, I didn't get what I want. Result is come out like that **[{"regis .......**

```
 var item = JSON.stringify(data['code']); //[{"registerCode":"SG_J1001"},{"registerCode":"SG_LS01"}]

 for(var i=0;i < item.length; i++){
     alert(item[i]);
 }
```

Comment: use the object as is. why are you stringifying?

Comment: If i right JSON.stringify make json as string, so you trying loop throug string?

Comment: @BOSS: I'm going to guess that the OP was confused by it alerting `Object object`. But yeah, they are doing it wrong.

Comment: You turned it from something you can loop over into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont stringify, and use dot notation to access the property of each index:

```
for(var i=0;i < item.length; i++){
    alert(item[i].registerCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do it like:

```
$.each(item, function(index,obj){
  alert(obj.registerCode);
});
```

See [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mh14d5a6/)

Comment: that is just too much for a simple iteration. a simple for loop would do

Comment: @BOSS Just giving an alternative in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Several correct posts here. 
One more rendition:

```
for (var key in data.code)
  alert(key.registerCode)
```